# Is it possible to see how <canvas> is being manipulated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm intrigued how this WebGL animation of the globe is being rendered:

http://ats-vs-world.cadillac.com/#!/home

[image]

Unlike other HTML elements, I haven't figured out a way to see how the canvas element is being manipulated.

In Chrome and other browsers, you can "Break on... subtree modifications", "Break on ... attributes modifications" and so on. With canvas, as it's being manipulated, the element sits blank.

Is there any way to do this?

**EDIT:** I really appreciate @Joe's answer. But is there still any way, in general (not specific to this website), so see how  is being manipulated?

Answer (score 2):

I definitely recommend [WebGL Inspector](http://benvanik.github.io/WebGL-Inspector/).

Other than that have you tried checking out the source? You can look at some items (shaders, textures) from Chrome's inspector.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has a canvas inspector in experimental phase (by the time I am writing this). To enable it, go to about:flags and enable "Developer Tools experiments". Then in developer tools settings (cog icon), go to experiments tab and you should see "canvas inspection" option - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/inspection/